# Programming/Security Issue

Tags: security, asp-classic, network-programming

I need some help on the best way to secure this situation.

Here is the background
This all runs on the internal network.
there is several small web sites with classic asp that runs on iis. they all pass username/pw through a form and call this class that is a dll on the server. Which then authenticates against active directory and returns back.  now obviously it is not secure passing through the form to the dll. is it then not secure as well from the dll to active directory?
what would be the easiest way to secure this. ssl? any other ideas and please answer that other dll question if you know

thanks

Comment: You can't use classic asp with C#, I don't understand why you have a C# tag.

Comment: what needs securing? Why is passing the form to the DLL not secure? Is the DLL not doing input checking?

Comment: @MystereMan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic+c%23 `:(`

Comment: Also, SSL is probably the wrong direction to go in. What you need is authentication, not encryption, and SSL is usually used to provide the latter. You _can_ use SSL to provide client authentication using client certificates, but then what's the point of the form and AD?

Comment: I just put c# because the class was coded in c# and thats the dll

Comment: when you submit your form with user name and password, reloads the page then calls the dll.. need to make it more secure

Comment: i'm nto sure if i'm explaining this right but its basically to prevent unsecure unecrypted passwords floating around between the application and checking against active directory.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the word "secure" is that it ia a highly subjective term.  What is or isn't "secure" really depends on the type of app and the damage that could be wrought if security measures are breached.

In some sense it isn't "secure" to have the password appear in memory in its unencrypted or even encrypted form.  However I will risk the wrath of the security fanatics and suggest that having a users password in your servers volatile memory is not going to risk thermo-nuclear war and therefore an acceptable risk.

As to communicating it to the AD well that doesn't actually happen, the password does not leave the servers memory to go elsewhere.  Instead AD formulates a challenge that the security API running locally in your server is able to build a response to armed with the password.  The response to the challenge is sent back to AD, this response does not carry the password but carries proof that the correct password was present.

Having said that, in an intranet environment going to all this trouble (and troubling the user to yet again enter their username and password) seems a bit execessive.  It would be better to just rely on Windows Integrated Security.

I've read your commens to SLaks re the "advised not to use NTLM".  Yes its true that with modern machines NTLM is not as secure as we might like but is it really too lax for your requirement?  Perhaps it is but integrated security can also use `Kerberos`.

So my suggestion would be ditch your dll, turn off NTLM in IIS leaving only Kerberos to handle the authentication.  This way you never transport the password anywhere, the user isn't troubled to re-enter their password, you need do nothing in code and you avoid using NTLM.

Comment: So everything that is unlikely enough to lead to a thermo-nuclear war is to be considered an acceptable risk? ;)

Comment: @Niklas:  It a moot point, for security fanatics every possible breach will lead to thremo-nuclear war :P

Comment: the web app and ad is not on the same server.

Comment: @Sirus: That is not significant, the password would still not leave the server running the web app.  The challenge from the DC will travel the network and so would the response, neither carries info from which the password can be derived.

Comment: So your saying if your on a network, using a web application and submitting a plain text password in a web form, then it calls a service which then sends that unencrypted password over the network to verify the correct password in Active Directory which resides on some other server. we are using NT authentication here. No one on the inside can't use some sort of packet sniffer?? come on dude, seriously

Comment: @Sirus:  I think you are getting a little confused about what I'm saying.  There are __3__ components here, the client (the browser), the web application (on your web server) and the domain controller (the part of AD that authenticates a user).   A plain text password in the client __will__ be sent over the network so you would have to use SSL for that stage of this forms based approach.  However once arrived on your web server the password will not then be passed over the network to the domain controller.  In fact by default even the AD doesn't know the users actual password.

Comment: Exactly lol, how was this even so hard for everyone to understand? I know, thats why i was talking about ssl or some other sort of encryption to fix this issue. Then i get all these crazy responses. Plus i never said AD would be sending the password anywhere.. I was talking about submitting the password over a form and then over the network dude. Like the one guy who respondes with "you can't use classic asp with c#" the classic asp calls a .dll that is programmed in c# on the IIS server.

Comment: @sirus: Programmers tend to prefer a much more precise use of language than "normal" people because we talk in languages which have to be very precise.  Your question lacked precision: "is it then not secure as well from the dll to active directory? what would be the easiest way to secure this. ssl?"  The dll runs on server the AD on another server, this question does not include the client.  I was already understood you are using SSL for client to server, your question appears to be about something after that.

Comment: lol, well i'm sorry if i didn't explain it properly. Just to clarify, there is no encryption anywhere.  internally you have a client that enters user/pass on a web app. This web app then passes the credentials through a form unencrypted, which then goes to .dll on the iis server. From there it passes it to AD for authentication which is on another server.  All i was asking was suggestions on securing this to avoid packet sniffing.. and yes ssl was an option. sigh